# Can't pass image to next script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I can't pass the image to my `upload.php` when trying to upload via mobile. Here's my code :

```
<form action="/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="picture" id="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" style="display:none;" onchange="submitForm();"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="sub_button" value="Submit" style="display: none">
</form>

<script>         
$('#IMG_1').click(function(){
     $('input[type=file]').click();
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm() {
    // However you need to submit the form
    document.getElementById("sub_button").click(); // Or whatever
}
</script>
```

I expect the image to be passed to `upload.php`, but nothing is being picked up on there. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: `submitForm` function is working ?? have you checked ?? so your form is not submitted ??

Comment: Which is the problem: is the form not submitting at all, or is the form submitting but the image data not being passed to `upload.php` as hoped?

Comment: The image isn't being passed @yortzec

Comment: What is the purpose of this function: `$('#IMG_1').click(function(){..})` ?

Comment: When the image which is the current profile is clicked, the camera will open up. @yortzec So its basically just a select image button

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the `Touch Event` or `Tap Event` when using a `mobile device`

An example of this event would be

[A Js Fiddle Example Is Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gianlucaguarini/NFH6m/)

You can find more information about this[Click Here](http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/detecting-the-tap-event-on-a-mobile-touch-device-using-javascript/)

Comment: How is this relevant to my question?

Comment: I thought you were having problems with the form on mobile. I am suggesting rewriting with `touch` or `tap` as opposed to `click`.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on my server, and it worked fine. Keep in mind that files uploaded through an HTML post form are actually passed into the global variable `$_FILES` instead of the usual `$_POST`. Could this be your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing on a mobile, iPhone for example. The images are very large and will timeout the script. Is the script producing any error?  Try setting the PHP memory to a higher amount.